# creating cutom products on the fly

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid

I'm builing a product configurator with highly complex “one-of-a-kind” products 
Unfortunately it is not possible for us to use shopify's product variants as we have a huge array of options, quantity discounts etc.

Is there a great way in creating cutom products on the fly?

**What we are looking for:**

- Create a product on the fly if the user click on the add-to-cart button.
- Add the custom product to the cart.
- Don't list the dynamically created products in the admin

So is this possible? Or is there another way

https://jsfiddle.net/ow0g6Lvs/

Thanks.

Regards,

Alex

Comment: yes you can, but using the [api](https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/product), not ajax cart.

Comment: Does using the api mean I have to create a shopify app?

Comment: yes, you only need to create a private app.